# Creating temporary files from native code in C++ in Android

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I am working on an Android project having native libraries in `C++`. Somewhere in the code, I encounter this line which tries to create a new file:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
dest_path = fs::absolute(make_public(fs::temp_directory_path())) / fs::path("tmp-" + to_string(u) + "." + extension);
fs::remove(dest_path);
fs::copy_file(*doc.get_path(), dest_path);
```

Now the boost API `temp_directory_path` returns the path for `/data/local/tmp` in Android. But seems like, an Android app is not allowed to create files at this location. Is there a way I can create files/folders at this location by giving permissions via `adb shell`?  Or Is there any alternative to the `/data/local/tmp` directory because I just need a temporary location and don't intend to store these files for long or how can I get the app's data directory in `ndk` or via `boost`?

Comment: Java's getFilesDir() gives `/data/data/<packagename>\files`.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to get the directory from the Java/Kotlin code during initialization of the library or class, replacing `fs::temp_directory_path()` with the value that you get from Java/Kotlin code.

For this I would probably use the app cache directory, by using [`Context.getCacheDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()). This will get you a `File` and you should get the absolute path (as native code doesn't use URIs but regular filesystem paths) by calling `file.getAbsolutePath()`.